# How would I get data from a Sqlite database then input it into TextViews

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I tried inputting data into a Sqlite database then getting it out to use when I input the data into textViews but when I press the button action it crashes. And I tried looking at where it when wrong in the Onclick and it said "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'Colour' does not exist" but I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDbHelper = new CarsDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,current_car_name);
        values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_COLOUR,current_car_colour);
        values.put(CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE,current_car_age);
        long newRowId = db.insert(CarsEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public void button (View view) {
        mDbHelper = new CarsDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
                CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE,
                CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE
        };
// Filter results WHERE "title" = 'My Title'
        String selection = CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { current_car_name };

// How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                CarsEntry.TABLE_NAME,                     // The table to query
                projection,                               // The columns to return
                selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                null,                                     // don't group the rows
                null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                null                                      // The sort order
        );

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            //Name
            current_car_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME));
            //Colour
            current_car_colour = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CarsEntry.COLUMN_COLOUR));
            //Age
            current_car_age = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE));
        }
        cursor.close();

        TextView car_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        car_name.setText(current_car_name);

        TextView car_colour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colour);
        car_colour.setText(current_car_colour);

        TextView car_age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);
        car_age.setText(String.valueOf(current_car_age));
    }
```

Comment: It says you do not have a column with the name `Colour`. Maybe you have mistake in writing column name

Comment: But i created a final string name which has a value of the string Colour

Comment: if you create db programmatically, remove app from your device/emulator and check again. if it does not work, include your dbhelper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In projection you have two times COLUMN_AGE and you make select with this column so you don't have on result COLUMN_COLOUR

```
  String[] projection = {
            CarsEntry.COLUMN_NAME,
            CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE,
            CarsEntry.COLUMN_AGE
    };
```